# Insert a Node at the Tail of a Linked List in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have my own linkedlist in eclipse and to insert a node at tail of linkedlist i have written a code -

```
void insertatlast( int data ) {
    Node insert = new Node( data );
    if( head == null) {
        head = insert;
        return;
    }

    Node temp = head;
    while(temp.next != null) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.next = insert;
    insert.next = null;
}
```

I have tried to solve this question on [Hackerrank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdjE0.png) but in it return type is not void so, I put:

```
return temp.next ;
```

but it is showing runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Solution.insertNodeAtTail(Solution.java:61)
at Solution.main(Solution.java:84)
```

Comment: On picture you have different code than you've posted in post. Also, please, format post properly, and post exact code that is giving you NPE.

Answer (score 1):

In the photo you have shared, a null pointer can occur, if the head itself was null.
you should modify you while condition to make sure that temp!=null

```
while(temp!=null && ...)
```